# No se como resolver un problema bastante simple

Tags: string, email

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola! Soy principiante y necesito que me quede (nombre de la persona)@?.com todo junto y en una misma línea, pero por algún motivo se salta a la línea siguiente al intentar juntarlos. Por otro lado, cuando lo hago al revés me queda justamente @?.com(nombre de la persona). Alguien me puede ayudar?
Muchas gracias

Comment: El código debe ir como texto por favor, recomiendo leas [ask]

Comment: Dale además un título _descriptivo_ a tu pregunta: recuerda que otros usuarios también podrían tener el mismo problema, y no llegarán a tu pregunta si esta tiene como título "no sé cómo resolver este problema" o similares. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta cambiar `line.split(",")` a `line.rstrip().split(",")` para remover los saltos de linea que vienen de la lectura del archivo de texto.

https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/rstrip.html

Comment: Muchas gracias!